# How to align the circles in a single line?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I am trying to make add the circles using the Tailwind Grid system. For the 5 option, it works fine but if I add 1 more circle the style collapse. I want to add a new Circle on the start name as None. How can I fix the styling?

Here is the Output:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/sgDu7UoViA

Should be like this:

[image]

> Code:

```css
.svg {
  fill: currentColor;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 66vmin;
  transform-origin: center;
  width: 135px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-gray-200 p-4 mt-2 text-black items-center flex grid grid-cols-5 gap-x-4 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-5 sm:gap-x-6 lg:grid-cols-6 xl:gap-x-8" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.08);">


  <div class="relative h-full flex justify-center items-center">
    <span class="absolute top-0 text-xs sm:text-sm font-medium text-black text-center mb-5 "> None </span>
    <label class="rounded-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center focus:outline-none ring-pink-500">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="mt-6 cursor-pointer h-24 w-24  border-opacity-10 rounded-full z-9">
                <img src="https://selection-app.netlify.app/assets/thumbnails/Rosehip.png" class="rounded-full" alt="">
            </span>
            <input type="radio" name="botanicals" data-id="botanicals"  class="sr-only">
        </label>
  </div>

  <div class="relative h-full flex justify-center items-center">
    <span class="absolute top-0 text-xs sm:text-sm font-medium text-black text-center mb-5 "> Rosehip Oil </span>

    <label data-id="Rosehip Oil" class="p-0.5 rounded-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center focus:outline-none ring-pink-500">
            
            <svg class="svg absolute rosehip_recommended_svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100" style="z-index: -1;"   >
                
                <defs>
                <path id="circle"
                    d="
                    M 50, 50
                    m -37, 0
                    a 37,37 0 1,1 74,0
                    a 37,37 0 1,1 -74,0"/>
                </defs>
                
                <text font-size="11" style="transform: rotate(-55deg); transform-origin: center;">
                    <textPath xlink:href="#circle" class="text-black versailles">
                        Recommendation based on your skin goals
                    </textPath>
                </text>
            </svg>

            <span aria-hidden="true" class="oil_label cursor-pointer h-24 w-24  border-opacity-10 rounded-full z-9">
                <img src="https://selection-app.netlify.app/assets/thumbnails/Rosehip.png" class="rounded-full" alt="">
            </span>
            <input type="radio" name="default_oil" data-title="Argan Oil" data-id="default_oil" value="Argan Oil_10" class="sr-only">
        </label>

    <div class="info_icon oil_info_icon absolute z-9 bottom-0" data-id="Rosehip Oil">
      <div class="flex justify-center">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 text-black -mt-16" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M13 16h-1v-4h-1m1-4h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="absolute text-xs sm:text-sm font-medium text-black bottom-0 mt-2"> Smooth </span>
  </div>

  <div class="relative h-full flex justify-center items-center">
    <span class="absolute top-0 text-xs sm:text-sm font-medium text-black text-center mb-5"> Marula Oil </span>
    <label data-id="Marula Oil" class="p-0.5 rounded-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center focus:outline-none ring-pink-500">
            <svg class="svg absolute hidden hidden marula_recommended_svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100" style="z-index: -1;"   >
                
                <defs>
                <path id="circle"
                    d="
                    M 50, 50
                    m -37, 0
                    a 37,37 0 1,1 74,0
                    a 37,37 0 1,1 -74,0"/>
                </defs>
                
                <text font-size="11" style="transform: rotate(-55deg); transform-origin: center;">
                    <textPath xlink:href="#circle" class="text-black versailles">
                        Recommendation based on your skin goals
                    </textPath>
                </text>
            </svg>
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="oil_label cursor-pointer h-24 w-24  border-opacity-10 rounded-full z-9">
                <img src="https://selection-app.netlify.app/assets/thumbnails/Rosehip.png" class="rounded-full">
            </span>
            <input type="radio" name="default_oil" data-title="Marula Oil" data-id="default_oil" value="Marula Oil_10" class="sr-only">
        </label>
    <div class="info_icon oil_info_icon absolute z-9 bottom-0" data-id="Marula Oil">
      <div class="flex justify-center">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 text-black -mt-16" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M13 16h-1v-4h-1m1-4h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="absolute text-xs sm:text-sm font-medium text-black bottom-0"> Smooth </span>
  </div>

  <div class="relative h-full flex justify-center items-center">
    <span class="absolute top-0 text-xs sm:text-sm font-medium text-black text-center mb-5"> Argan Oil </span>
    <label data-id="Argan Oil" class="p-0.5 rounded-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center focus:outline-none ring-pink-500">
            <svg class="svg absolute hidden argan_recommended_svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100" style="z-index: -1;"   >
                
                <defs>
                <path id="circle"
                    d="
                    M 50, 50
                    m -37, 0
                    a 37,37 0 1,1 74,0
                    a 37,37 0 1,1 -74,0"/>
                </defs>
                
                <text font-size="11" style="transform: rotate(-55deg); transform-origin: center;">
                    <textPath xlink:href="#circle" class="text-black versailles">
                        Recommendation based on your skin goals
                    </textPath>
                </text>
            </svg>
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="oil_label cursor-pointer h-24 w-24  border-opacity-10 rounded-full z-9">
                <img src="https://selection-app.netlify.app/assets/thumbnails/Rosehip.png" class="rounded-full">
            </span>
            <input type="radio" name="default_oil" data-title="Argan Oil" data-id="default_oil" value="Argan Oil_10" class="sr-only">

            
            <div class="oil_label_checked_icon absolute inset-x-0 top-0 transform translate-y-px hidden">
                <div class="flex justify-center transform -translate-y-1/2">
                    <svg class=" h-6 w-6 text-green-600 ml-10 mt-20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm3.707-9.293a1 1 0 00-1.414-1.414L9 10.586 7.707 9.293a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414l2 2a1 1 0 001.414 0l4-4z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                    </svg>                                              
                </div>
            </div>
        </label>
    <div class="info_icon oil_info_icon absolute z-9 bottom-0" data-id="Argan Oil">
      <div class="flex justify-center">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 text-black -mt-16" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M13 16h-1v-4h-1m1-4h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="absolute text-xs sm:text-sm font-medium text-black bottom-0 mt-2"> Smooth </span>
  </div>

  <div class="relative h-full flex justify-center items-center">
    <span class="absolute top-0 text-xs sm:text-sm font-medium text-black text-center mb-5"> Jajoba Oil </span>
    <label data-id="Jajoba Oil" class="p-0.5 rounded-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center focus:outline-none ring-pink-500">
            <svg class="svg absolute  Jajoba_recommended_svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100" style="z-index: -1;"   >
                
                <defs>
                <path id="circle"
                    d="
                    M 50, 50
                    m -37, 0
                    a 37,37 0 1,1 74,0
                    a 37,37 0 1,1 -74,0"/>
                </defs>
                
                <text font-size="11" style="transform: rotate(-55deg); transform-origin: center;">
                    <textPath xlink:href="#circle" class="text-black versailles">
                        Recommendation based on your skin goals
                    </textPath>
                </text>
            </svg>
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="oil_label cursor-pointer h-24 w-24  border-opacity-10 rounded-full z-9">
                <img src="https://selection-app.netlify.app/assets/thumbnails/Rosehip.png" class="rounded-full">
            </span>
            <input type="radio" name="default_oil" data-title="Jajoba Oil" data-id="default_oil" value="Jajoba Oil_10" class="sr-only">

            
            <div class="oil_label_checked_icon absolute inset-x-0 top-0 transform translate-y-px hidden">
                <div class="flex justify-center transform -translate-y-1/2">
                    <svg class=" h-6 w-6 text-green-600 ml-10 mt-20" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm3.707-9.293a1 1 0 00-1.414-1.414L9 10.586 7.707 9.293a1 1 0 00-1.414 1.414l2 2a1 1 0 001.414 0l4-4z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                    </svg>                                              
                </div>
            </div>
        </label>
    <div class="info_icon oil_info_icon absolute z-9 bottom-0" data-id="Jajoba Oil">
      <div class="flex justify-center">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 text-black -mt-16" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                    <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M13 16h-1v-4h-1m1-4h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <span class="absolute text-xs sm:text-sm font-medium text-black bottom-0 mt-2"> Smooth </span>
  </div>

  <div class="relative h-full flex justify-center items-center">
    <span class="absolute top-0 text-xs sm:text-sm font-medium text-black text-center mb-5"> Almond Oil </span>
    <label data-id="Almond Oil" class="p-0.5 rounded-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center focus:outline-none ring-pink-500">
            <svg class="svg absolute Almond_recommended_svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="100" height="100" style="z-index: -1;"   >
                
                <defs>
                <path id="circle"
                    d="
                    M 50, 50
                    m -37, 0
                    a 37,37 0 1,1 74,0
                    a 37,37 0 1,1 -74,0"/>
                </defs>
                
                <text font-size="11" style=" transform: rotate(-55deg); transform-origin: center;">
                    <textPath xlink:href="#circle" class="text-black versailles ">
                        Recommendation based on your skin goals
                    </textPath>
                </text>
            </svg>
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="mt-16 oil_label cursor-pointer h-24 w-24  border-opacity-10 rounded-full z-9">
                <img src="https://selection-app.netlify.app/assets/thumbnails/Rosehip.png" class="rounded-full">
            </span>
            <input type="radio" name="default_oil" data-title="Almond Oil" data-id="default_oil" value="Almond Oil_10" class="sr-only">

            <div class="info_icon oil_info_icon z-9" data-id="Almond Oil">
                <div class="flex justify-center transform -translate-y-4    ">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="h-6 w-6 text-black mt-4" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M13 16h-1v-4h-1m1-4h.01M21 12a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z" />
                    </svg>                                           
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class=" text-xs sm:text-sm font-medium text-black bottom-0 mt-2"> Smooth </span>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you mean you just want it in flex position like in horizontal position? If so let me know.

Comment: Yes Horizontal position @Crystal

Comment: how many you want to add?

Comment: I just want add 1 more on the start @Crystal

Comment: I want to add a total of 6 in a horizontal position @Crystal

Comment: see the code below if that will work for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243883/discussion-between-crystal-and-saad-masood).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this. Then let me know.

```css
  @media (max-width: 639px) {
  .sm\:grid-cols-3 {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(0, 1fr));
  }
```

```html
<div class="bg-gray-200 p-4 mt-2 text-black items-center grid grid-cols-6 gap-x-4 gap-y-8 sm:grid-cols-6 sm:gap-x-6 lg:grid-cols-6 xl:gap-x-8"  style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.08);">
```

Comment: Thanks but the circles are not responsive on mobile view. See this link : https://play.tailwindcss.com/sgDu7UoViA

Comment: What do you want to make it small or you want them to wrap?

Comment: When on mobile view it should be grid-cols-3

Comment: I mean on mobile view it should be 3 circles in each horizontal position. For now the heading and the info icon collapse when i add 1 more on the start

Comment: let me put your code here

Comment: did you edit both codes? don't change anything i sent the entire code on the chat room for you so you can see the entire code and that works.

Comment: I did not change anything

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243885/discussion-between-crystal-and-saad-masood).